# Is there any way to buy a new car directly from Toyota without going through a dealership?

Tags: car

I'm so tired of haggling with the dealers at a local Toyota dealership. They are not only pressing, but also aggressive, condescending and mean.

I want to cut the middleman. I know exactly what I want. Is there any way I could order a car directly from Toyota? Will this save me the money?

I don't like the idea of paying the middleman. Those lot fees, the commission. I read on Yahoo that this is possible, but what is the best way to go around this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37773/discussion-on-question-by-melinda-is-there-any-way-to-buy-a-new-car-directly-fro).

Comment: You might try a different dealership further away and/or in a smaller town.  A friend of mine would phone dealers in smaller towns barely within driving distance.  He tell them what he wanted, the price he was willing to pay and was clear that he wanted minimal paperwork/fussing at the dealership.  He refused to haggle or get drawn into extended discussions.  "Here's what I want and here's what I'm willing to pay."  He started early, gave himself the luxury of time eventually a dealer called back that was willing to meet his price and terms.

Comment: There is a humorous short video on this topic: [Adam Ruins Everything - The Real Reason Car Dealerships Are the Worst](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMWmYJOa-BM)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

No you can't buy direct from Toyota.  Largely because of many states' laws (assuming you're in the US) requiring a dealer relationship for car purchasing, read about Tesla's struggles with direct to customer sales.  Secondly because Toyota corporate simply isn't set up to sell a car directly to a customer.

I know there are services that help people through the buying process.  If you're finding Toyota dealerships to be this difficult you may consider just buying something from someone who wants to sell to you.  If the buying process is this difficult imagine the service relationship.

Edit: Additionally, it's important to remember when financing a car that there are essentially two transactions taking place.  First you're negotiating the price of the car.  Then you negotiate the price of the money (the interest rate).  The money does not need to come from the dealership, you can secure your financing rate from a separate bank or local credit union.  You should definitely pursue alternate financing if they're quoting you 7.99% with a FICO of 710.  But don't tell the dealership you've already got your financing lined up until you're happy with the price of the car.

Comment: Often manufacturers will have a quote feature. You can "build your own" custom package on their website and they will forward it to the dealer of your choice for quote. This could help as a starting point for negotiations.

Comment: See other answers about case shopping, which have good advice about how you deal with dealers on a more even basis... And why buying a new car may be a mistake financially.

Comment: @jkuz, Often the dealer will then get that build quote and find something on their lot as close as they can and tell you to come for a test drive today!  They'd rather sell what's on their lot so you're still going to deal with some BS trying to get _that_ car ordered.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Ah yes, that makes sense. I have never used that service myself. Some of these places don't understand that 'no' is a complete sentence.

Comment: "But don't tell the dealership you've already got your financing lined up until you're happy with the price of the car." Can you explain a bit about why OP shouldn't do this? (It seems obvious to me but I can see how someone new to car buying wouldn't make the same jump to conclusion)

Comment: @TylerH If you tell them upfront you have your own financing, they'll have less reason to negotiate on the price of the car. If you get financing through the dealership, they'll pretend to give you a great deal upfront because they know they'll recoup the discounts through interest over time.

Comment: @Ivan well normally dealers are just loan originators, and the capital is provided by another entity like Hyundai Motor Finance. But I agree that it's best not to mention separate financing, since the dealer has some incentive to arrange a loan in any case.

Answer (score 42):

I feel your pain. It probably depends on your state, but two things we've tried with some benefit:

1. Purchasing through Costco, which meant that the dealer didn't negotiate price or features with us - although they did spend an hour at the end trying to sell us extra-cost options like extended warranty, road service, etc. The hilarious thing is if you research those extra-cost things, the internet will tell you **none** of them is a win. I guess duh - they are a win for the dealer or the manufacturer.
2. Our nicest experience was many years ago in California, where we bought through a broker (google 'auto brokers') - we told them what we wanted, they found it and gave us the price, I think they even delivered it.  Just make sure you get a well-reviewed broker; your bank or credit union might have recommendations.

Comment: +1 for buying through Costco, the Consumer Reports Car Buying Service (TrueCar), or a reputable broker.

Comment: I had no idea Costco sells cars...can you buy just 1, or do they come in packs of 10?

Comment: @coburne It's sort of like AMEX and some other credit card companies - they have a "services" department which sells things like vacation packages, home repair, cars, etc., acting as an agent basically.  Often at very reasonable prices.

Comment: Even if you buy through Costco, you would still be making use of an Authorized Toyota Dealer. The way it works is that Costco refers you to a partnering dealership with whom they have pre-negotiated deals. You go to the dealer telling them that Costco sent you there, and you get the Costco members' price.

Comment: Is the Costco price better than the Internet / Fleet price?

Comment: @Michael When I looked two years ago it was an OK price, I would not have any problem sending my mom there and having her pay that price.  I am an unrepentant bargain hound, so I was able to bring myself to pay that price, and was able to beat it by a fair amount by being a good shopper.  But if you just hate the process, go the Costco route and be happy.

Comment: @Ukko So... no?  The reason I ask is I bought a vehicle about 5 years ago and I requested quotes from all the "Internet" managers in the area. They were all within about $200 of each other and slightly below the Edmunds "True Price", so I picked the closest dealer. While I was there after most of the paperwork was done I noticed the Costco thing lying around and asked about it and he claimed that price was more than what I was paying.  By that point it was too late to fact check, but I was just curious if that was really true.

Comment: @coburne If you're getting such a package, you should see if they can throw in the multi-story car-carrying truck for free.

Comment: @Michael You probably did a bit better than the Costco price which is better than the advertised price.  There is often not much wiggle room in new prices, since the cars and customers are interchangeable and commodities.  To get a deal you need a special circumstance. For instance I saved $4k buying a car that had been parked inside the showroom lobby.  It was about 18 months old with 12 miles on it, a great deal but not one I will ever duplicate.

Comment: Didn't know about Costco but I had a great experience with a broker 11 years ago.  They quoted a price for the specific (new) car + accessories I wanted and my research indicated it looked fine.  They found the car at a dealer about 30 miles from my home.  I paid them $400 directly via credit card then got a cashier's check (I was paying cash) for the agreed price minus $400 (their fee), took it to the dealer, got asked a perfunctory "undercarriage? LoJack?" by a finance guy who didn't care at all that I said no, then drove off with the car within 30 minutes.

Answer (score 15):

You could consider buying a fairly recent used car from CarMax. They have fixed pricing, and you'd save a good amount of money on the car (since cars lose tons of value in their first year or so).

Comment: Cars lose like 10-20% of their 'value' as soon as they're driven off the lot, even.

Comment: Here in MD, CarMax sells Toyotas new, also with the fixed prices.

Comment: When looking for a used car for our kids to drive we found that buying a "certified" used car was a good deal. The car we found (2011 Honda Civic, purchased in early 2014) had come in off a three year lease with 18k miles on it. The dealer did all service, inspected, oil, filters, etc, etc, and sold us the car at a reasonable price. Just suggesting this as an option. If you can find a low-mileage used car it could save you some money.

Answer (score 15):

Any car manufacturer that undercuts their own dealer network would have that network fall apart quickly.  Tesla is using a dealer-free distribution model from the start, so they don't have that problem.  Toyota doesn't work that way, though.

GM imposed a uniform no-haggling policy with their Saturn brand, but that policy was coupled with [local monopolies for dealers](http://knowledge.wharton.upenn.edu/article/saturn-a-wealth-of-lessons-from-failure/) to make it work.  [Lexus](http://autoweek.com/article/car-news/lexus-try-no-haggle-pricing) has also experimented with no-haggling and online ordering (with delivery still taking place at a dealership).  The rest of Toyota doesn't work that way, though.

Some car manufacturers, such as [BMW](http://www.bmwusa.com/Standard/Content/Explore/Experience/EuropeanDelivery/OrderYourBMW.aspx) and [Audi](https://www.audiusa.com/inventory/european-delivery), allow you to take delivery of your new car at the factory for a discount. But even then, the transaction still takes place through a dealer.  Toyota doesn't work that way, though.  For one thing, they work at a different scale.  If you buy a Camry in the US, it might be [produced in Kentucky, Indiana, or Aichi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Toyota_manufacturing_facilities), depending on business conditions.

You say that you want to cut out the middleman, but the fact is that you do require someone to deliver a Toyota to you, like it or not.

If you're interested in saving money, consider trying various well documented tips, such as negotiating by e-mail before showing up, pitting dealerships against each other.  If you don't want to negotiate, you might be able to take advantage of [pre-negotiated dealer prices through Costco](http://www.costcoauto.com/).

You mentioned that the dealership offered you a 7.99% interest rate for your 710 FICO score.  That sounds insanely high — I'd expect deals more like 2% advertised by [buyatoyota.com](http://www.buyatoyota.com/en/).  (Remember, Toyota Motor Credit Corporation exists to help Toyota Motor Corporation sell more cars cheaply.)  You can also seek alternate financing online [(example)](https://roadloans.com) or through your own bank.

Answer (score 13):

If there's one reasonably close to you, you could go to a no-haggle dealership.  Instead of making you haggle the price downward, they just give a theoretically fixed price that's roughly what the average customer could negotiate down to at a conventional dealer.  Then just do your best broken record impression if they still try to sell you dubious addons:  "No.  No.  No.  No.  No..."

The last time I bought a new car (06), a no haggle dealer offered the second best deal I got out of 4 dealerships visited.  The one I ended up buying with made an exceptional offer on my trade (comparable to 3rd party sale bluebook value). - My guess is they had a potential customer looking for something like my old car and were hoping to resell it directly instead of flipping it via auction.

Comment: +1 for this.  The one I used was the most friendly place I ever worked with and had real perks I could use.  While the other places was giving me a run around on prices, the cars on this lot was priced clearly on the window.  When I asked the sales lady why they was cheaper, she was straight up about how they got that price and what discounts where in place.  In an hour I had exactly the car I was looking for lined up (they had to do a dealership trade to get it).

Comment: My latest car was purchased (actually, leased) from a (newly converted to) set-price Honda dealership.  Good price, good buying experience.  And I knew from 10 years of previous visits that their service department was very very good, so I was quite happy to get the car from them.  (And they didn't even push me for addons, just pointed to the brochures laying around and left it at that.)

Answer (score 4):

sadly, it is illegal in most states to buy a car directly from the manufacturer. as such, most manufacturers do not offer the option even where it is legal.

if you really do know exactly what you want (model, color, options, etc.) i recommend you write down your requirements and send it to every dealer in town (via email or fax).  include instructions that if they want your business, they are to reply via email (or fax) with a price within 7 days.  at least one dealer will reply, and you can deal with whoever has the best price.

notes:

1. i believe this buying method is from the book "the millionaire next door"
2. the laws banning direct-to-consumer car sales may go away soon. particularly if tesla gets it's way.
3. some car dealers offer "no haggle" pricing, but there may not such be a toyota dealer in your area.
4. there are some new business models in the used car market like [beepi](https://www.beepi.com/) and [carvana](http://www.carvana.com/) that might interest people fed up with the car dealer experience.

Comment: I've used this method to purchase several cars. It works particularly well for used cars when you know what features you want but don't necessarily care about the make/model.

Comment: @JustinOhms brilliant!  i shall have to try that next time i am in the market. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can buy a new Toyota from a non-dealer, but not from Toyota directly as they have no retail distribution capability.

There is no need to buy directly from Toyota if you want to get a new car without going through a dealer.

In many cases people buy new cars but have to sell them immediately for one reason or another.

Answer (score 3):

As someone who was just recently a salesman at Honda, I'd recommend buying a Honda instead :). If you really prefer your Toyota, I always found quote-aggregation services (Truecar, I'm blanking on others) very competitive in their pricing.

Alternatively, you could email several dealerships requesting a final sale price inclusive of taxes and tags with the make, model, and accessories you'd wish to purchase, and buy the vehicle from them if your local dealership won't match that price. Please keep in mind this is only persuasive to your local dealership if said competitors are in the same market area (nobody will care if you have a quote from out-of-state).

As many other commenters noted, you should arrange your own financing. A staple of the sales process is switching a customer to in-house financing, but this occurs when the dealership offers you better terms than you are getting on your own. So allow them the chance to earn the financing, but don't feel obligated to take it if it doesn't make sense fiscally.

Answer (score 3):

1. No, Toyota only  sells through franchised dealers.  Saves factory money and lowers their risk.
2. By federal law all franchised dealers pay an identical amount for identical vehicles. HOWEVER, and this is very important various incentives and contests factory runs will change the amount of money "after incentives and rebates" by thousands of dollars per vehicle often.  So dealer A may own the Camrly Le for $2500 less than dealer B After the incentives that each has earned on a performance incentive.  This is known in the industry as stair step pricing and the dealers have lobbied for a "level playing field" for years to no avail. 
   If you have a trade in shop it with CarMax and some independents on what they will write a check for and own it today. Then call around ask what the out the door price including DOC fee's all in would be on the  exact unit equipment  you want.  All True Car, Costco, Credit union "Buyer Services" Do is get paid $500 per car by the dealer for the lead "name" generated. That's money you could keep. there isn't a Toyota store I know of that wont sell a unit for invoice less half the hold back and pass all the incentives to get another unit out the door.   the "salesman/order taker is working for a $50 mini per unit in most cases and will be lucky to clear $32000 a year if he puts in 80 hours a week.   Just the facts.

Answer (score 2):

As others have addressed the legality in their answers, I want to address the idea of the dealership being 'a middleman'.

A dealership serves more of a purpose than just 'middlemanning' a car to a consumer. Actually, they consume a great deal of risk. Let's remember that a dealership is really an extension of the OEM, albeit independently owned and operated, the dealership must still answer to the brand they represent, if people have a bad experience with a dealership, a customer might go to another of the same brand, but more often than not they will go to the competition out of spite. Therefore, it's in the dealership's best interest to represent the brand as best as possible, but unfortunately that doesn't always happen.

While the internet has made a certain part of a salesman's role null and void, and since this is a finance (read money) Q/A site let's take a moment to consider the risk assume and therefore the value *added* by a dealership:

- **Test Drive**. A car is a huge purchase, and while it's okay to buy a pair of shoes online without trying them on, a car is a bit different of course, we want to make sure it 'fits' before we shell out several thousand dollars. Yes, you (meaning consumers) can look at car pictures and specs online, but if you want to see how that vehicle handles on your town's roads, if it fits in your garage and/or driveway, then you need to take it for a test drive. It's not feasible for OEMs to have millions of people showing up to car plants for a test drive, right? Scalability aside, some business that is handled in automotive plants are confidential and not for the general public to know about. A dealership provides an opportunity for those who live locally to see and experience the car without flying or driving wherever the car was assembled. They provide this at a *risk*, banking on the fact that a good experience with the vehicle will lead to a sale.
- **Service**. A car is a machine, and no machine is perfect, neither will it last forever without proper service. A dealership provides a place for people to bring their vehicles when they need to be serviced. Let's set aside the fact that the service prices are higher than we'd like, because the fact remains most of it is skilled (and warrantied) labor that the majority of people don't want to do themselves.
- **Trade Ins**. It is not in an OEMs best interest to accept a vehicle just to sell you another vehicle, *especially* if that vehicle is from another brand. Dealership's assume this *risk*, and often offer incentives to do so, hoping it will lead to a sale. That trade in was an asset to you, but is a liability to them, because they now have to liquidate that trade in, just so that you can purchase a car. Sure, you could sell your car yourself, and now you would assume that risk: What if your car is not in perfect shape, or has a lot of miles for it's age? Would it do well in the used car market? What if it takes too long to sell and you miss that Memorial Day car sale at the dealer? This might be okay for some, but generally speaking most people would rather avoid the risk and trade it in at the dealer toward the purchase of a new car rather than the headache of selling it themselves.

I'm sure there are more, but those are the one's that immediately sprung to mind. Just like Starbucks, there are terrible dealerships out there and there are great ones, and very few of us venture to farms and jungles just for fresh coffee beans :-)

Comment: Uh, yeah, but in this case the "risk" is so high that the dealers in my area (Seattle) are minting money and have been for some time.  Just look at the new car palaces for BMW, Mercedes, Audi, and Honda/Toyota built in the city in the last 5 years.  I wish I could live in one of Audi's service bays - they're that beautiful.

Comment: I have to assume the BMW/Mercedes dealership looks vastly different than a Toyota dealership :-), but you're right most dealerships look very nice on the inside. In their defense though, BMW Audi and Mercedes are luxury car lines, so everything about them has to say 'luxury' for the sake of the brand. And we can probably say their core customer base doesn't mind spending the extra capital for it.

Comment: At least #1 and #2 on your list really don't require a dealership, as Tesla demonstrates.

Comment: @Voo tell me more, where do I go to test drive a tesla?

Comment: @big [You're welcome](https://www.teslamotors.com/models/drive)

Comment: I already saw that @Voo, I was hoping you could expound on that, as all that is a sign up page that promises to contact me tomorrow.

Comment: [There's more information on the site](https://www.teslamotors.com/support/test-drive) if you're curious. But the particulars don't really matter, just that it is clearly possible to do test drives without involved dealerships.

Comment: @Voo Fair enough, although 1) Let's not forget Tesla still has 'Stores', so I'd hazard a guess that their solution for representatives traveling from state to state w/ a Tesla or two doesn't exactly scale well, but that _is_ just an educated guess. I will agree though that at least the first point can be supplied without a dealership, although the quality of that is questionable. The second point though, where exactly would I take a Tesla for service, as there is a Tesla 'store' in Michigan, but the service center is 'Comin Soon' according to the website.

Comment: It sounds like Tesla is trying to offer everything a dealership has except for a salesperson, which is their choice given capitalism. Also, there is a difference between a $70k car and _any_ Toyota, the revenue generated allows them to do things more affordable car lines cannot, if they want to stay in business.

Comment: Not all of those things actually require a dealership. The financing, service dept. and trade-ins can easily be done elsewhere, for often better prices/rates than the dealer. There are independent, skilled mechanics that do warrantied service for often much less than the dealer. They are not trying to make up for missed dealer sales quotas. And for trade-ins, you can sell you car to Carmax or similar without any hassle (assuming your car runs well). No need for placing ads. A dealer only uniquely offers a place to test and buy locally. Otherwise, you'd have those large trucks in neighborhoods.

Comment: I'm imaging that Tesla uses the same sort of service as the "We'll pick you up" deal from car rental companies. One "store" has a few models, when you want to test drive, they come over in the one you want, you drive it. If you like it, you place your order and get a brand new one. Or maybe you keep that one and the store orders another for test drives. I would have thought it would be better to keep the floor model separate, just like when you buy computers or TVs or whatever. That way the customer always gets an unused machine. Just speculating though.

Comment: @fractalspawn I didn't mean to imply that the dealership is the _only_ place to get those services, but that they add other value than just a 'middleman', if that makes sense :-)

Comment: @BigHomie: Touché :)

Answer (score 2):

You already got good answers on why you can't buy a Toyota from the factory, but my answer is regarding to the implied second part of your question: how to avoid haggling.

I found a good way to avoid the haggling at a car dealership can be simply to not haggle. Go in with a different attitude. The main reason car dealers list inflated prices and then haggle is that they expect the customers to haggle. It is fundamentally based on distrust on both sides. Treat the sales person as your advisor, your business partner, as somebody you trust as an expert in his field, and you'll be surprised how the experience changes. Of course, make sure that the trust is justified.

Sales reps have a fine line to walk. Of course they like to sell a car for more money, but they also do not want a reputation of overcharging customers. They'd rather you recommend them to your friends and post good reviews on Yelp. In the end, all reputable dealers effectively have a fixed-price policy, or close to it, even those who don't advertise it, and even for used cars. Haggling just prolongs the process to get there.

And sales reps are people. Often people who hate the haggling part of their job as much as you do.

I was in the market for a new (used) car a few months ago. In the end, it was between two cars (one of them a Toyota), both from the brand-name dealer's respective used car lots. In both cases, I went in knowing in advance what the car's fair market value was and what I was willing to pay (as well as details about the car, mileage, condition etc. - thanks to the Internet). Both cars were marked significantly higher. As soon as the sales rep realized that I wasn't even trying to haggle - the price dropped to the fair value. I didn't even have to ask for it. The rep even offered some extras thrown into the deal, things I hadn't even asked for (things like towing my old car to the junk yard).

Comment: Very well said, a salesperson will never haggle 'first', it's always the consumer that tries to get the car for cheaper, and often get mad when the salesperson won't come down to the price the consumer wants. The salesperson states the price they are willing to sell the car for, and that's that. An educated buyer doesn't need to haggle, you know what the car costs, their commission is already built into the msrp. Do we haggle with the people at McDonalds?

Comment: This is totally true. When I bought my last car, I went in having already calculated the original price, minus 15-25 cents per mile (like they charge you on a lease), minus initial decline in value from being driven at all. When you know how much the car actually costs, you don't need any of their numbers. Especially when your math is spot on. Best deal ever. @BigHomie: The difference between a car and hamburgers, though, is that all BigMacs cost the same, not more in Beverly Hills vs Inglewood. If they didn't, I'd suspect people would haggle for them.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, nothing is impossible! :) You can buy it directly from the factory of manufacturer, but then you will have to pay for sea shipping of this car. E.g. you can buy it directly from Japanese Toyota but then you will have to pay to sea cargo ship to deliver your car in container from Japan. Since this car is already your property, before importing to US, I doubt that you would need to pay any custom fees. In the end, the total payment might be a lot cheaper that you can buy there, but you need to be prepared to all this hassle

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I suspect you got -1 because this is all just logical assumptions in an ideal situation. It makes sense in dreamland (where I also like to live), that you can just show up at the manufacturers and drive one "hot off the presses", but you haven't really provided any sources to back your claim. You also don't seem to know that many Toyotas are built here in the states, likely to avoid that import fee you speak of (and to provide jobs/PR cred). With as many Toyotas as are on the road, importing all of them would be insanely expensive and slow.